# does safe_strcpy in samba checks if the memory allocation was successful

Tags: c, malloc, samba, strcpy

I am trying to copy a string to another using `safe_strcpy` but can't seem to find the function definition.

This is what am doing:

```
 char value[256];
 char *var = NULL;
 var =  malloc(sizeof(value));
 safe_strcpy(var, value, strlen(value)+1);
```

I wanna know if I need to add error handling for `malloc` or does `safe_stcpy` takes care of it?

Comment: you need to check for `malloc` success.

Comment: Is there some missing code that actually puts data into `value`?

Comment: You should be able to find the `safe_strcpy()` implementation in `lib/util/util_str.c` of the SAMBA source assuming the version of SAMBA you have uses it. Allison removed `safe_strcpy()` and friends in 2011: https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commit;h=ff215f5c89c91a22c910400c8ac81d82d7459ba0

Comment: Yes. I didn't add the code to initialize value here. Thanks for the pointer to samba repo. I think I ll have to add safe check for malloc.

Comment: A couple notes: the `maxlength` argument is supposed to be the size of the destination buffer not including the space for the terminating null. So in your example it should be `sizeof(value)-1`. Also, according to the commit comment that removed `safe_strcpy()` SAMBA switched to using `strlcpy()`. It seems to me that that might be a good way to go for your own code to use instead of `safe_strcpy()` since `strlcpy()` is a pretty widely used 'safe' alternative to `strcpy()` and has a well documented/understood interface.

Answer (score 0):

In the [current source code](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=tree) of samba I cannot find any function called 'safe_strcpy'. I can find `alpha_strcpy`, described in the comments as a 'Paranoid strcpy', which I suspect has replaced that previous function you were asking about, although it has a different prototype with an additional argument.

Anyway:

```
char *alpha_strcpy(char *dest,
                   const char *src,
                   const char *other_safe_chars,
                   size_t maxlength)
{
        size_t len, i;

        if (!dest) {
                smb_panic("ERROR: NULL dest in alpha_strcpy");
        }
```

So, this function at least does check the dest, but if it is null it will panic, which is probably not what you want.

I recommend you **always** check the return value of malloc yourself.

Comment: You are right. 'safe_strcpy' seems to have been replaced by 'strlcpy'. Found 'safe_strcpy' in older versions: apparently it returns 'null' when destination string doesn't have memory allocated. So I guess I'll have to add the check.